# python pyscripter define error

Tags: python, undefined, pyscripter

Hello my name is Luke and i am having a define error with my fruit machine code, the word skull is defined but it says that it's not and i can't understand why. if you could help me that would be great and thank you for spending your time trying to fix this.

```
import random

symbols = ["cherry","bell","lemon","orange","star","skull"]
credit=100

x=1

while x == 1:

yn = input ("ready to play (y or n)")
if yn == "y":
    print("You have this much credits:")
    print (credit)
    print ("ok lets start roleing")
    credit = credit - 10

else:

    print ("why are you here then? go away")
    exit()

wheel1 = random.choice(symbols)
wheel2 = random.choice(symbols)
wheel3 = random.choice(symbols)

print (wheel1 + "-" + wheel2 + "-" + wheel3 + "-")

if wheel1 == wheel2 == wheel3 == skull:
    print ("you got 3 skulls you lose all of your money,thank you for playing")
    exit()

elif wheel1 == wheel2 == wheel3 == star:
    print ("################################")
    print ("#                              #")
    print ("#        BIG JACK POT          #")
    print ("#                              #")
    print ("################################")

    credit = credit + 1000

    print("YOU GOT THE BIG JACKPOT AND GOT 1000")
elif wheel1 == wheel2 == wheel3 == cherry:
    print ("################################")
    print ("#                              #")
    print ("#          jack pot            #")
    print ("#                              #")
    print ("################################")
    credit = credit + 500

    print("you got the small jackpot and got 500")

elif wheel1 == wheel2 == wheel3:
    print ("################################")
    print ("#                              #")
    print ("#       small jack pot         #")
    print ("#                              #")
    print ("################################")

    print ("you got the small jack pot and got 250")
    credit = credit + 250
elif wheel1 == wheel2 == skull:
    print ("you got 2 skulls - 10 credits")
    credit = credit - 10

elif wheel1 == wheel3 == skull:
    print ("you got 2 skulls - 10 credits")
    credit = credit - 10

elif wheel2 == wheel3 == skull:
    print ("you got 2 skulls - 10 credits")
    credit = credit - 10

elif wheel1 == wheel2 :
    print ("mini prize you got 10 credits")
    credit = credit + 10

elif wheel1 == wheel3 :
    print ("mini prize you got 10 credits")
    credit = credit + 10
elif wheel2 == wheel3 :
    print ("mini prize you got 10 credits")
    credit = credit + 10


else:
    print("you got nothing,better luck next time")
```

Comment: But you DIDN'T define ``skull`` anywhere - you have a string composed of those characters inside of a list, but no part of that constitutes a definition.  Either put quotes around it everywhere it appears (just as you did in your ``symbols`` list), or put ``skull = "skull"`` near the top to actually define the name.

Comment: ok i am sorry for the inconvenience i asked my teacher and she just said that python was broken thanks for you help anyhow and i hope you have a nice day